# Window resizing problems in Xcode example

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I've downloaded [Apple's example GLEssentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html). Then added a programmatically window resizing in a method *awakeFromNib* in *GLEssentialsWindowController* class implementation:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
  NSRect rect = [view convertRectToBacking:NSMakeRect(0,0,500,500)];
  [self.window setFrame:rect display:YES animate:NO];
}
```

Here comes the most of fun. When I doing such simple operation on my working iMac there is no problems at all. Window size becomes what I expected.
But when I doing this operation on my MacBook window resizes to value stored in *.xib* file. Then I manually resize window to some new size and quit from application. Then launch it again. Window resizes to the size that this window had at the last launch right before it was closed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, *NSOpenGLView* class calls resize method even after window is initialized, that's why the only solution to do not allow window to resize right after *awakeFromNib* event is remove resizable mask from window styles:

```
[window setStyleMask:[window styleMask] & ~NSResizableWindowMask];
```

So the final solution will look like:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
 [self.window setStyleMask:[self.window styleMask] & ~NSResizableWindowMask];
 NSRect rect = [view convertRectToBacking:NSMakeRect(0,0,500,500)];
 [self.window setFrame:rect display:YES animate:NO];
}
```

So the target window will be resized to 500 x 500, and doesn't matter what the size was stored in *.xib* file.